# How can I apply 3D-transformations to an image?

Tags: c#, c++, image-processing, gimp, gdkpixbuf

I am trying to (in code) take an image file and apply three dimensional transformations (think: perspective) to it.

The application I'm working on is written in C#, and I've already looked at the [MSDN info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b575a03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on skewing/rotating images.  Unfortunately, this is not enough control -- I need the functionality offered by the "Perspective" tool that GIMP/Photoshop offer.

I'm already using P/Invoke to call the following C++ DLL's (got them out of the GIMP /bin folder) for other image functionality:

```
[DllImport("libgobject-2.0-0.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[DllImport("librsvg-2-2.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[DllImport("libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
```

This approach seems to work well for what I need to do (rasterize a vector image), and it keeps all of the code inside the application (I'd rather not have to go the commandline route -- I know GIMP can be scripted, but that's sort of a last resort right now).

I'd like to figure out a way to use these libraries (libgdk-pixbuf-2.0, libgobject) and others, if needed, to accomplish the three dimensional transforms I need to do.

Anyone have any suggestions?  I'm open to other ideas, but really like the idea of using those opensource libraries to get the job don

Comment: If you want to write the software yourself, look into affine transforms. .NET has support for them, last I checked.

Answer (score 1):

Open CV has [warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective) function which is exact to your need.
For working in C#, you might consider [Emgu.cv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/658c5511-a5f9-6180-3271-637ab5c8022a.htm) a c# wrapper to OpenCV.